# Problem with init file with new Emacs 25.1 on OSX

Tags: init-file

After installing the new Emacs 25.1 (universal binary) on my Mac OSX 10.11.6 I got the following init error after starting with --debug-init. I don't know what to do. Can you help me?

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function set-fringe-mode)
  (set-fringe-mode (quote (5 . 5)))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-808999> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-bindings.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffe$
```

**UPDATE**:
After solving `fringe-mode`problem I got new ones: This is the new debug-init:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function (quote (["Comment Out Region" comment-region (c-fn-region-is-active-p)] ["Uncomment Region" (comment-region (region-beginning) (region-end) (quote (4))) (c-fn-region-is-active-p)] ["Indent Expression" c-indent-exp (memq (char-after) (quote (40 91 123)))] ["Indent Line or Region" c-indent-line-or-region t] ["Fill Comment Paragraph" c-fill-paragraph t] "----" ["Backward Statement" stan-beginning-of-statement t] ["Forward Statement" stan-end-of-statement t] ["Backward Block" stan-beginning-of-block t] ["Forward Block" stan-end-of-block t] ["Mark Block" stan-mark-block t] "----" ("Style..." ["Set Style..." c-set-style t] ["Show Current Style Name" (message "Style Name: %s" c-indentation-style) t] ["Guess Style from this Buffer" c-guess-buffer-no-install t] ["Install the Last Guessed Style" c-guess-install (and c-guess-guessed-offsets-alist c-guess-guessed-basic-offset)] ["View the Last Guessed Style" c-guess-view (and c-guess-guessed-offsets-alist c-guess-guessed-basic-offset)]) "----" ("Toggle..." ["Syntactic indentation" c-toggle-syntactic-indentation t] ["Electric mode" c-toggle-electric-state t] ["Auto newline" c-toggle-auto-newline t] ["Hungry delete" c-toggle-hungry-state t] ["Subword mode" c-subword-mode t]))))
  signal(invalid-function ((quote (["Comment Out Region" comment-region (c-fn-region-is-active-p)] ["Uncomment Region" (comment-region (region-beginning) (region-end) (quote (4))) (c-fn-region-is-active-p)] ["Indent Expression" c-indent-exp (memq (char-after) (quote (40 91 123)))] ["Indent Line or Region" c-indent-line-or-region t] ["Fill Comment Paragraph" c-fill-paragraph t] "----" ["Backward Statement" stan-beginning-of-statement t] ["Forward Statement" stan-end-of-statement t] ["Backward Block" stan-beginning-of-block t] ["Forward Block" stan-end-of-block t] ["Mark Block" stan-mark-block t] "----" ("Style..." ["Set Style..." c-set-style t] ["Show Current Style Name" (message "Style Name: %s" c-indentation-style) t] ["Guess Style from this Buffer" c-guess-buffer-no-install t] ["Install the Last Guessed Style" c-guess-install (and c-guess-guessed-offsets-alist c-guess-guessed-basic-offset)] ["View the Last Guessed Style" c-guess-view (and c-guess-guessed-offsets-alist c-guess-guessed-basic-offset)]) "----" ("Toggle..." ["Syntactic indentation" c-toggle-syntactic-indentation t] ["Electric mode" c-toggle-electric-state t] ["Auto newline" c-toggle-auto-newline t] ["Hungry delete" c-toggle-hungry-state t] ["Subword mode" c-subword-mode t])))))
  c-get-lang-constant(c-mode-menu (cc-langs) stan-mode)
  byte-code("\302\303\304\305   \306=\203\307\202\310\311\312\313#B$\207" [stan-mode-map c-version-sym easy-menu-do-define stan-menu "Stan Mode Commands" "Stan" 5\.32\.5 (["Comment Out Region" comment-region (c-fn-region-is-active-p)] ["Uncomment Region" (comment-region (region-beginning) (region-end) (quote (4))) (c-fn-region-is-active-p)] ["Indent Expression" c-indent-exp (memq (char-after) (quote (40 91 123)))] ["Indent Line or Region" c-indent-line-or-region t] ["Fill Comment Paragraph" c-fill-paragraph t] "----" ["Backward Statement" stan-beginning-of-statement t] ["Forward Statement" stan-end-of-statement t] ["Backward Block" stan-beginning-of-block t] ["Forward Block" stan-end-of-block t] ["Mark Block" stan-mark-block t] "----" ("Style..." ["Set Style..." c-set-style t] ["Show Current Style Name" (message "Style Name: %s" c-indentation-style) t] ["Guess Style from this Buffer" c-guess-buffer-no-install t] ["Install the Last Guessed Style" c-guess-install (and c-guess-guessed-offsets-alist c-guess-guessed-basic-offset)] ["View the Last Guessed Style" c-guess-view (and c-guess-guessed-offsets-alist c-guess-guessed-basic-offset)]) "----" ("Toggle..." ["Syntactic indentation" c-toggle-syntactic-indentation t] ["Electric mode" c-toggle-electric-state t] ["Auto newline" c-toggle-auto-newline t] ["Hungry delete" c-toggle-hungry-state t] ["Subword mode" c-subword-mode t])) c-get-lang-constant c-mode-menu (cc-langs) stan-mode] 9)
  require(stan-mode)
  byte-code("\300\301!\210\300\302!\207" [require stan-mode yasnippet] 2)
  (stan-snippets-initialize)
  (lambda nil (stan-snippets-initialize))()
  eval-after-load-helper("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20160801.1142/yasnippet.elc")
  run-hook-with-args(eval-after-load-helper "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20160801.1142/yasnippet.elc")
  do-after-load-evaluation("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20160801.1142/yasnippet.elc")
  require(yasnippet)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-202317> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-completion.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 226
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-completion.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-completion.el" nil nil)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-completion.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-completion.el")
  org-babel-load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-completion.org")
  starter-kit-load("starter-kit-completion.org")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-77724> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3859
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil nil)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el")
  org-babel-load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.org")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3581
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\266 \306=\203\307\310Q\202? \311=\204\307\312Q\202?\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202?\313\307\314\317#\203>\320\321\322!D\nB\323\202?\316\324\325\324\211#\210\324=\203e\326\327\330\307\331Q!\"\325\324\211#\210\324=\203d\210\203\247\332!\333\232\203\247\334!\211\335P\336!\203\201\211\202\214\336!\203\213\202\214\314\262\203\245\337\"\203\243\340\341#\210\342\343!\210\266\f?\205\264\314\325\344\324\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Could you check if `fringe-mode` works? Just eval `(fringe-mode '(5 . 5))`.

Comment: It evaluates to `((vertical-scroll-bars) (left-fringe . 5) (right-fringe . 5)`. I tried to comment `fringe-mode` but others errors started to show.

Comment: I think it's a problem with your init. You should try to see what's going on there. Try bisecting/disable starter-kit-bindings and see if it's still reproducing.

Comment: I commented out references to minimal-mode and fringe-mode in starter-kit-bindings and starter-kit-misc and the result of emacs --debug-init is now (part of):  `require(yasnippet)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-591772> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-completion.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 226
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-completion.el"`

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies in your `load-path`? Do you run `package-initialize` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it's the first line of my init.el. Let me say that everything works fine in version 24.

Comment: hmm... I have updated today on MAC and Linux and it works fine. But I deleted my .emacs.d and reinstalled all my packages... Maybe if you install and recompile all your packages will fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, how can I do that? What folders do I have to delete (after backup)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original poster is suffering from two (2) distinct issues.

**Issue #1**:  The first issue is resolved by placing `(require 'fringe)` at the top of the `.emacs` file, saving the modified file, and restarting Emacs.  The first error message tells us that the function `set-fringe-mode` has not been defined yet, and a quick `grep` of the Emacs lisp source-code reveals that the function at issue is contained in the library `fringe.el`.  If we open up `fringe.el`, we can see that it contains a `provide` statement at the bottom of the file -- so a `require` statement in the `.emacs` file is sufficient to load the entire `fringe.el` file (assuming it is in its default location within the `load-path`).  We put the `require` statement at the top of the `.emacs` file because we are guaranteed that it will load first in time -- before whatever else in the user-configuration is calling a function from that library.

**Issue #2**:  The second issue/diagnosis was identified by @npostavs as being a known problem with `stan-mode` incapatibality with Emacs 25:  https://github.com/stan-dev/stan-mode/issues/47  There are a few general approaches  (1) disable `stan-mode` in the user-configuration and don't use it; (2) wait patiently for a fix from the `stan-mode` maintainers; (3) dig-into `stan-mode` and `cc-mode` and contribute to fixing Github issue number 47; or, (4) go back to a previous version of Emacs where `stan-mode` still plays nice with `cc-mode`.

Comment: Solved fringe problem but the init error remains: `Eval error in the ‘c-lang-defconst’ for ‘c-mode-menu’ in stan-mode:`I have no space for `debug-init`output.

Comment: You will need to debug one error at a time, and debug output similar to what was listed in the question above would be helpful.  The one-liner debug output just isn't enough to go on other than telling us there is a problem loading `stan-mode`, whatever that is.  Either edit the question above using something like a separator to indicate it is an update, and mention the progress made so far . . ., or launch a new question dealing with the new error.

Comment: I have edited the initial question with an update.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and suggest try placing `(require 'cc-mode)` on the line following `(require 'fringe)`, but that's not a guarantee it will fix it.  If it works, then great -- if not, let me know please and I'll keep spinning my mental wheels.  Most of the functions mentioned in the debugger message (containing the edited material) are loaded by `cc-mode` and related libraries that get triggered/loaded.

Comment: @sbac: looks like `stan-mode` doesn't support Emacs 25 (apparently due to changes in cc-mode), see [stan-mode#47](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan-mode/issues/47)

Comment: @lawlist: using `require 'cc-mode` did not work.

Comment: After posting my previous comment, I found `stan-mode` on the internet and saw that it requires `cc-mode` at the outset when `stan-mode.el` loads.  It looks like @npostavs has already identified the problem by citing Github `stan-mode` issue number 47.  So, you've got four (4) general choices:  disable `stan-mode` in your user-configuration and don't use it; wait patiently for a fix from the `stan-mode` maintainers; or dig-into `stan-mode` and `cc-mode` and contribute to fixing Github issue number 47; or, go back to a previous version of Emacs where `stan-mode` still plays nice with `cc-mode`.

Comment: Yes I have just disabled `stan-mode`and `stan-snippets`and now Emacs 25.1 works finally! Do you want to write an answer for me to vote?

Comment: I updated the answer and gave credit to @npostavs for identifying the `stan-mode` issue number 47 on Github.